# Remove Trailing slash on Nuxt application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am working with Nuxt Application.

when I make a build running the **npm run build** command and starting it with **npm start** command

it doesnt seem to show any trailing slash

so on my build its like this http://localhost:3000/blog

but when I deploy the site at first it runs smooth with no trailing slash but once I **refresh** the page it loads the page with a **trailing slash**

example of the result http://example.com/blog/

I tried using all kinds of middleware and even the Nuxt **trailingSlash** method. but no luck

here is how my nuxt.config file looks like

```
var dynamicPages = require('./dynamicPages.json')

export default {
  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: 'server',
  // buildDir: '_nuxt/dist/',
  // build: {
  //   publicPath: '_nuxt/dist/'
  // },

  generate: { routes: dynamicPages },

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'level-1',
    description: "level-1",
    author: "Rick",
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico',
        href: "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;300;400;500;600;800;900&display=swap",
      },
    ],
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
    '~/assets/styles/style.scss',
    '~/assets/fonts.css'
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/analytics.js', mode: 'client' }
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/google-analytics'
  ],

  apollo: {
    clientConfigs: {
      default: {
        httpEndpoint: "https://rickandmortyapi.com/graphql"
      }
    }
  },

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/bootstrap
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    'nuxt-helmet',
    '@nuxtjs/apollo',
    'nuxt-helmet',
    'nuxt-webfontloader',
    '@nuxtjs/gtm',
    'nuxt-fontawesome',
  ],


  router: {
    trailingSlash: false,
  },

  fontawesome: {
    imports: [
        {
          set: '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons',
          icons: ['fas']
        },
        {
          set:'@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons',
          icons: ['fab']
        }
    ],
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    extractCSS: true
  },
}
```

Comment: What happens if you navigate to a page after the refresh? This is probably not a Nuxt thing but more of a server configuration here IMO. It adds the trailing slash after the refresh I guess.

Comment: if I refresh the current page for example /blog, it loads the same request url but adds a slash at the end resulting /blog/

Comment: Yep, it's what you wrote in your question so far. What about my comment? Try to move from blog to another page via the vue-router.

Comment: I did so I moved from /blog/ to about us and it ended with /about. the trailing slash only occurs when refresh the page

Comment: Yep, this is not a Nuxt related issue so. But the platform/server configuration, adding it to your URL.

Comment: I also manually tried removing the trailing slash form /blog/ to /blog and when i press enter it still ends up with /blog/ do you think that is also not related to nuxt?

Comment: Yep, I'm still thinking that this is unrelated to Nuxt. Try to host your app somewhere else or dive deep into the documentation of your server/platform.

Answer (score 0):

It might be Nuxt doing its own internal redirection. Nuxt decides to add a slash when you have the same name folder in the static folder as you page filename.

So if you have */static/blog*, try renaming it to something else.

If this is not the case, I would suspect the server is doing the redirection.

Comment: Why would somebody have a directory of the same name in `/static`? Quite strange use-case.

Comment: It happend to me few hours ago. Usually images are stored in folder `/static` (not processed by webpack). And to structuralize your static folder, it makes sense to use the same folder name as the name of the page in which the images are used.
For example, every image on `/pages/blog.vue` could be saved in folder `/static/blog/`.

Comment: Why would you not optimize your images? Sounds quite not performant to me, it's probably one of the heaviest assets on the Web.

Comment: Who said that the images are not optimized beforehand? Also, there might svg files or other downloadable documents (pdf). My point stands.